# Using the verb ござんす ["to be"] in modern Japanese

Tags: copula, archaic-language, style

If I use the verb ござんす

As in

> [しからばこの身を お疑いでござんすか](https://forvo.com/word/%E3%81%97%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E3%81%B0%E3%81%93%E3%81%AE%E8%BA%AB%E3%82%92_%E3%81%8A%E7%96%91%E3%81%84%E3%81%A7%E3%81%94%E3%81%96%E3%82%93%E3%81%99%E3%81%8B/#ja)
>
> So, do you doubt me?

Will it be similar to English "*Art thou doubting me*" or will it give my speech a refined flavour or perhaps a dialectical one ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ござんす is an **un**sophisticated variant of ござります/ございます. Typical users of ござんす are (obsequious) merchants, craftsmen, geisha, rōnin, etc. in samurai dramas. It is very unlikely that a truly noble person or a high-ranked samurai speaks this way in dramas and movies. Of course, modern people never speak this way unless they are imitating someone.

Comment: I know ございます is used quite frequently in Keigo but what about ござります in modern speech ?

Comment: @JapaneseLearner ござります is no longer used in modern speech. Both ござんす and ございます are slurred versions of ござります, but only the latter somehow bacame the standard.

Comment: Thank you so much @naruto ! I think it is still important to know if you like historical dramas or religious texts. Similar to English knowing words like "thou, thee, whomst, whither, hither etc]